# how to fix Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server in my code like this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
export default function Page({ data1 }) {
  const [bookmark, setBookmark] = useState(
    typeof window !== 'undefined'
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmark'))
      : []
  );

  const addToBookmark = (ayatLs) => {
    setBookmark([...bookmark, ayatLs]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('bookmark', JSON.stringify(bookmark));
  }, [bookmark]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="modal-body">
        <ul>
          {bookmark.map((x) => (
            <li key={x.nomor}>{x.tr}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
    {data1.map((x)) => (
      <div className="pb-6 flex justify-between">
        <span
          onClick={() => addToBookmark(x)}
          className={`text-sm `}>
          {x.tr}
        </span>       
      </div>  
    )}
```

When i use `typeof window !== 'undefined'` the `Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server in my code like this`.

and when i change to `localStorage.getItem('bookmark')` the error is `localStorage is not defined`

when i click addToBookmark it will store data from props data1 to localStorage, no problem here, but when I fetch the data earlier in localStorage and I want to map the data that error appears

What's wrong with my code, why can't I map data from localStorage, please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Move the `localStorage` data gathering and parsing to another `useEffect` instead and set the state in there. In your first `useEffect` check if `bookmark` is not an empty array before setting the data in `localStorage`. It should work with these changes.

Comment: can you type the code for me, i still don't understand

Comment: See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Comment: see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76051589/3073272

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that Next.js pre-renders pages by default, which means they are rendered on the server first and then sent to the client to be [hydrated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydration_(web_development)).

The error comes when you're setting the default value of the state based on this condition: `typeof window !== 'undefined'`.

Consider the following example:

```
const Page = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? 'Peter' : 'Rick')
  
  return <h1>{name}</h1>
}

export default Page
```

This code will throw an error of the type `Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.`

If you inspect the page's source, you will see that the name rendered on the server was "Rick" while on the client-side's first render the name rendered was "Peter". There must be a match between the server-side rendered content and the client-side first render's content.

What you can do is move the `localStorage` data gathering and parsing logic to another `useEffect` instead and set the state in there. This solves the issue because `useEffect` only runs on the client-side, therefore you will effectively match both server-side and client-side first render content.

```
export default function Page({ data1 }) {
  const [bookmark, setBookmark] = useState([])

  const addToBookmark = (ayatLs) => {
    setBookmark([...bookmark, ayatLs])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (bookmark.length === 0) return
    localStorage.setItem('bookmark', JSON.stringify(bookmark))
  }, [bookmark])

  useEffect(() => {
    const bookmarkFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('bookmark')

    const parsedBookmark =
      bookmarkFromLocalStorage !== null
      ? JSON.parse(bookmarkFromLocalStorage)
      : []

    setBookmark(parsedBookmark)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div className='modal-body'>
        <ul>
          {bookmark.map((x) => (
            <li key={x.nomor}>{x.tr}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```